# Chrome Not Starting When Using ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium and ChromeDriver to write a scraping job. When I run the following code though nothing happens, in the sense that Chrome doesn't appear to start, but I don't get an error.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(r"http://www.python.org")
time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

Is there something else that I need to do to make Chrome start?

Comment: Don't see any issue with the code. Do you get any error?

Comment: No errors. No warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download chromedriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and put it in your path. I also see that you have a typo in driver.get, make sure you have a correct URL as well

Below is the typo I was talking about

```
driver.get(r"http://www.python.org")
```

Comment: I have chromedriver.
I don't see the typo. What should it be?

Comment: Because I'm an idiot I'd grabbed the 32 bit driver, not the 64 bit driver.